# C++ Защита от SuspendThread

Tags: c++

У меня тут вопрос, как можно защититься от того чтобы твой процесс не заморозили?
Был вариант перехватить эту функцию, чтобы не дать ему заморозить, но как то от этого толку не было или я просто не правильно перехватывал, не знаю.
Есть ли вообще другие варианты, слышал что можно как то с таймером это реализовать, если не трудно покажите пример. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Начнём с того, что ваш процесс могут запустить под Bochs или другим эмулятором процессора.

Comment: а можно какую нибудь банальную защиту, просто от обычноый заморозки?

Comment: Ну, вы можете снять права всем на доступ к вашему процессу (смотрите [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880(v=vs.85).aspx)), но процесс с администраторскими правами сможет эти права вернуть. Вы в любом случае проиграете процессу, который запущен до вас, можно только постараться задать ему побольше работы.

Comment: Почитайте на досуге [это](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040216-00/?p=40603/) и [вот это](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253/) (второе не вполне по теме вначале, но стоит прочитать комментарии).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, почитаю на досуге.
А что насчет перехвата ф-ии?

Comment: @HackMemory и как мы будем разбираться, что у вас не работает? Выкладывайте код.

Comment: Если хочешь перехватить SuspendThread(), то придётся его подменять во всех приложениях, вместе с ResumeThread(), ведя статистику заморозки со стороны. Ибо ResumeThread() возвращает предыдущее значение счётчика заморозки. Не факт что suspend'ящее приложение будет проверять возврат ResumeThread(), но лишним не будет.